# log4j error on eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

For some reason, I am getting the following error for logs. After doing some research and some comments from the previous posts, I have created a log4j file, but it still does not work. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.http.impl.conn.BasicClientConnectionManager).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

Comment: Can you post your log4j file? How are you configuring it?

Comment: The log4j file should be in base directory or in resource folder

Comment: I have kept it in the src/ folder of where I created my code files. Let say src/test/java is the path of my files. I have kept them in src folder. Should it be okay ?

Comment: I have added it to src folder and it worked like charm. I just need to create a brand new project Java (without Maven) and placed the log4j.properties file. It worked good. I have also changed the log level from DEBUG to INFO. I got the output exactly how I need. Thank you very much chsdk and Murthi.

Answer (score 1):

this is the manual please read through it 
[URL for official manual](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html)

the very first thing you can do is in your main method call this

```
BasicConfigurator.configure();
```

or you can also add this in your **log4j.properties**

```
# Set root logger level to DEBUG and its only appender to A1.
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, A1

# A1 is set to be a ConsoleAppender.
log4j.appender.A1=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender

# A1 uses PatternLayout.
log4j.appender.A1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.A1.layout.ConversionPattern=%-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n
```

just make sure log4j.properties file is in your eclipse project classpath

Comment: the error says we can not find log4j.xml or log4j.properties file. 
its a file used by log4j library to configure logging properties this is just  a warning

Comment: I have added it to src folder and it worked like charm. I just need to create a brand new project Java (without Maven) and placed the log4j.properties file. It worked good. I have also changed the log level from DEBUG to INFO. I got the output exactly how I need. Thank you very much Adeel.